# For what types of differential equations is the Laplace transform most effective?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm reviewing for a final exam and want to make sure I know what tools to use for what situations, and was just wondering if there were situations where the Laplace transform is unusable or less effective, and in which situations it is most effective.

Comment: Linear equations, especially (but not only) with constant coefficients. Laplace transform may be used for other types of equations, but it's less straightforward. See an example of the "easy" case here: http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/solve/solve.html